# Using ZXing for scanning 0.5 x 0.5 cm code

Tags: iphone, sdk, zxing

I am using ZXing in my iphone app. The problem:

I have to scan this [image](http://imageshack.us/content_round.php?page=done&l=img580/1082/imagetoscan.png&via=mupload&email=tyrexl@yahoo.com&newlp=1) that has 0.5 x 0.5 cm dimension and it does not scan it. Furtheremore the bar code image is not very clear. Is there a way I can edit the captured image before ZXing processes it?

One thing might be the fact that the colors are inverted. Any idea where to start from?

Comment: Any ideea how to do the same to the Android version of Zxing? I compiled the project as jar. I integrated it in my project. Now if i want to make any changes I must modify it in the original Zxing project and recompile the jar and integrate it once again to test the changes? I mean if i want to invert colors and make adjustments shall I recompile the jar every time or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code needs to be black-on-white to be scanned -- scanning inverted codes is not required by the relevant specs, so most don't. Just invert it first.

Comment: Ok. Now I am at this point. It scans but not in the right manner. To slow I would say. I rotated the image to the position that it scans, I monochromed the image and inverted colors. The result is [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/823/captureblured.png/)  .